# Should I put "The" before "Another"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Suppose I want to write in an academic paper,

> We have two ways to approach the problem. One approach is use .... *Another* approach is to ...

Should I put the article '*the*' before *another*?

Comment: *Another* is a run-together form of *an other*. Since you wouldn't say *I play the a banjo*, you shouldn't say this either.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not.  As noted in the comment 'Another' does not ever take an article.

But you might wish to say 'The other', if there are only two.